# How to specify a regional location for Google BigQuery JDBC driver?

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery

I am trying to specify a the `asia-northeast1` (Japan) location for the [SIMBA BigQuery JDBC driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/) to use when querying a dataset in that location. For regional locations you must specify your location when querying:

> If your data is in a location other than the US or EU multi-region, you must specify the location when you perform actions such as loading data, querying data, and exporting data. [Specifying your location](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-locations#specifying_your_location)

I have tried setting my query string subname to:

```
//https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2;ProjectId=mybqproject;OAuthType=3;Location=asia-northeast1
```

It's in Clojure, so the whole thing is here for context, but the same principles should apply for any JDBC connection.

```
(clojure.java.jdbc/get-connection
   {:classname   "com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.Driver"
    :subprotocol "bigquery"
    ;; OAuthType=3 means use Application Default Credentials
    :subname     "//https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2;ProjectId=mybqproject;OAuthType=3"})
```

It doesn't appear as if the Location property is picked up (I just guessed about using `Location` here, I couldn't see anything in the docs). I am able to successfully connect to and query against datasets in the US multiregion, so the configuration properties are correct but not Japanese ones. When I try and query a dataset in Japan I get this error:

```
CompilerException java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not found: Dataset mybqproject:mybqtable",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not found: Dataset mybqproject:mybqtable"
},
```

I get this error in the BigQuery SQL console also when I don't explicitly set the Japan location. This indicates that the Japanese location is not being searched for this table.

How can I choose the Japanese location when using the Google BigQuery SIMBA JDBC driver?

Answer (score 1):

The Simba JDBC driver unfortunately doesn't support this feature yet, so you won't be able to use it that way.

https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/options/intro-general.htm (processing location is not listed)

If possible, you could switch to using the BigQuery API and set the field `jobReference.location`. Set it to the processing location you want, using the query job configuration. **Note**: this is marked as `Experimental` so be careful.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I don't think it works to set that property in the JDBC driver (yet?).

Comment: Yeah, I don't thinks it's supported yet with the Simba driver. I'll update my answer.